# Simulink block to generate points from equation

Tags: function, matlab, simulink

I need help in Simulink, I am looking for a way to generate an array as the outputs from Simulink block like if `t=0:1:10`s then `x = 2sin(t)`, I know only of the block that gives constant value of `x`. This is the model block:

[image: block]

Highlighted blocks give constants; I want to replace them with any block that would generate an array using equation such as instead of `x=50` it will give `x=2sin(t)`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a code related question and if it is if [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The block I was looking for is 'fcn'. It is only available in Matlab 2020a and below, that's why I couldn't find it (I have 2021a). Hope it helps anybody else.

[This is what it looks like, you can just write your equation in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i0dU.png)